# Eclipse for Django - searching and/or replacing for a word in all CLIENT-SIDE scripts within a web-project

Tags: django, eclipse, ide

I use Eclipse for developing a Django project. And I suffer much from inability to open my JS/HTML scripts in Eclipse so that I can, say, search and replace all occurrences of a certain string project-wide. In the past, I used to work with PyCharm, where it possible to open python scripts as well client-side files. In Eclipse, it's not possible.

The question is - is there any way to import the client-side files of a web-project into Eclipse in a way that would enable to Ctrl+F a string in not only python scripts, but also in JS and HTML

Comment: What do you mean by inability to open js scripts, they open using system editor? Or they are located in a directory outside of your python project?

Comment: Well, I am talking about the client-side files that are located in the "static" folder. I don't mean that the files cannot be opened using Eclipse. Actually, they can be opened. What I mean is that they are not included in the workspace as is the case with PyCharm, resulting in inability to search for a string occurrence not only in python scripts, but also in static files, irrespective of whether they are currently opened in the editor or not.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just create a parallel project linked to your static folder.

Comment: Great idea, will try it.